# gedit flashes on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, gedit, text-editor

I am having a problem every time I try to open `gedit`. The txt file opens and starts to flash. I cannot control it and I cannot see the content of the txt document. The only way out is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. 
This is happening every time I try to open gedit (whether from the terminal or when opening a `txt` file).

I would really appreciate your help! Thanks.

### EDIT

Following what Ravan suggested, I followed the link and typed `gvfs-info -a metadata FILENAME`.

The output was:

`attributes:
  metadata::gedit-position: 2035828
  metadata::gedit-position:: 2035828
  metadata::nautilus-icon-position: 
  metadata::screen:`

and then I wrote `gvfs-set-attribute FILENAME metadata::ATTRIBUTE ''` for each `metadata` entry.

And then when I rewrite`gvfs-info -a metadata FILENAME`, the output becomes:

`attributes:
  metadata::gedit-position: 2035829
  metadata::gedit-position:: 2035828
  metadata::gedit-position::: 2035828
  metadata::nautilus-icon-position: 
  metadata::nautilus-icon-position:: 
  metadata::screen: 
  metadata::screen::`

I am still having the same problems when I open `gedit`.

Comment: please refer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/408157/gedit-flashes-and-exit-automatically-when-opening-a-file)  ,it seems to be a bug. try this `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install gedit`

Comment: I reinstalled it. However it didn't work. `gedit` still flashes whenever I open it. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: have you followed the link I provided!

Comment: yes, when I type `gvfs-info -a metadata FILENAME` the output is: `attributes:
  metadata::gedit-position: 2035828
  metadata::nautilus-icon-position: 
  metadata::screen:`